# Azure functions returning 500 without error

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an azure function which is called by the API management endpoint.
On the client code I get an Internal Server Error exception (http 500), but if I see the application insights I have no error in the function itself:

[image]

The problem is that I only get an status 400 of the cosmosdb but the query execute successfully after that. Why I´m getting this behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked "Monitor" blade of your Azure function ? Generally ,you can get error logs there .

Comment: If the operation performed in the test involves a database, such as inserting data operations, if the large amount of data causes the table space in the database to be full, or the database connection pool is small and cannot satisfy the data access, etc.  These may cause HTTP500 error. Adjust the database and modify the connection pool size. Maybe other problems, check your code self or show your code on forum.

Comment: The returned 500 error may be due to a failed operation on the database.

Comment: @StanleyGong yes, on the function logs it says that the result is "Success" but the status is 500.

Comment: Function returned 500, so API management layer worked correctly. Double checking - the question is why Azure Function returned 500?

Comment: Are you using input and output bindings?